# Understanding why list is fixing abstract method type

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Ive create a class with two abstract method.

In one method I return my generic type U in a list as required by the return type in my abstract method List

In my second method I just return U as required by the return type in my abstract method  but I get a type error
 error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type `LB.HexSphereBuild.HexTile' to`HexTile'

I dont understand why this is an implicit conversion? Especially since all the types are under LB.HexSphereBuild namespace apart from my public abstract class AStarFindPath which is using LB.HexSphereBuild;

Please help

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

using LB.Managers;
using LB.HexSphereBuild;


namespace LB.AStarPathFinding
{
    public abstract class AStarFindPath<T,U> : MonoBehaviour{

        public virtual void FindPath<T>(Vector3 startPos, Vector3 targetPos) {
        }

        // Method 1
        public abstract U NodeFromWorldPoint<T,U> (Vector3 worldPos);

        // Method 2
        public abstract List<U> GetNodeNeighbours<U> (U node);
    }

}
```

Here is the class inheriting my abstract class

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

using LB.Managers;
using LB.AStarPathFinding;

namespace LB.HexSphereBuild
{

    [RequireComponent (typeof(PlanetBuildManager))]
    public class AStarHexSphere: AStarFindPath<Hexsphere,HexTile>
    {

        private HexSphere _hexSphereObj;


        void Awake ()
        {

            // Reference to HexSphere 
            _hexSphereObj = gameObject.GetComponent<PlanetBuildManager> ().hexSphereObj;
        }


        override public HexTile NodeFromWorldPoint<HexSphere,HexTile> (Vector3 worldPos )
        {

            int startNodeIndex = _hexSphereObj.GetHexIndexFromPoint (worldPos);
            int startNodeIndex = _hexSphereObj.GetHexIndexFromPoint (worldPos);
            HexTile startHex =  _hexSphereObj.Hexes[startNodeIndex];// error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type `LB.HexSphereBuild.HexTile' to `HexTile'
            return startHex;
        }

        override public List<HexTile> GetNodeNeighbours<HexTile> (HexTile node )
        {

            List<HexTile> neighbours = new List<HexTile>();
            List<int> hexNeighboursIndices = new List<int>();
            int hexIndex =0;
            _hexSphereObj.GetNeighbors (hexIndex, ref hexNeighboursIndices);

            return neighbours;
        }

        public void FindPath (Vector3 startPos, Vector3 targetPos)
        {
            // Get HexTile from start and end positions
            int startNodeIndex = _hexSphereObj.GetHexIndexFromPoint (startPos);
            HexTile startHex = _hexSphereObj.Hexes [startNodeIndex];
            int targetNodeIndex = _hexSphereObj.GetHexIndexFromPoint (targetPos);
            HexTile endHex = _hexSphereObj.Hexes [targetNodeIndex];

        }
    }

}
```

Adding in the property incase the problem is here

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System;

namespace LB.HexSphereBuild
{
    [System.Serializable]
    public class HexSphere
    {
        private List<HexTile> _hexes = new List<HexTile> ();
        // Data for the hexes. Read only
        public List<HexTile> Hexes {                             
            get{ return _hexes; }
        }
        // ....... other stuff
    }
}
```

Adding the data class

```
namespace LB.HexSphereBuild
{
    public class HexTile : IAStarPathFinding<HexTile>
    {
        // Code .....
    }
}
```

Comment: Try defining Constraint for Generic Type. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters for reference.

Comment: When I constraint it simply tells me im missing a cast error CS0266: Cannot implicitly convert type `LB.HexSphereBuild.HexTile' to `HexTile'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: Where is the HexTile defined?

Comment: Its defined in it own class under namespace LB.HexSphereBuild. Ill add it aswell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already defined `T` and `U`, defining them in your methods *again* means the `T` in all methods might be a different type. That's not what you want, remove the generics on the methods:

```
public abstract class AStarFindPath<T,U> : MonoBehaviour
{
    public virtual void FindPath(Vector3 startPos, Vector3 targetPos) 
    {
    }

    // Method 1
    public abstract U NodeFromWorldPoint(Vector3 worldPos);

    // Method 2
    public abstract List<U> GetNodeNeighbours(U node);
}
```

Comment: Lol that it !! . Thanks so much nvoigt